# Removing Telephone Required Validation only on registration

Tags: validation, magento

I'm looking for help with removing telephone validation. As I understand it can be done by overriding `Mage_Customer_Model_Address` class. But I need it only at register page, so it still be as required field in customer **My account** page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override template `/customer/form/register.phml` in your package/theme, not a model! In your new `register.phtml` template file just remove `class="required"` from the telephone field.

Comment: I'm enabling address fields by adding `<action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value></action>` to `customer.xml`. For some reason even if I fill out all address fields after pressing "Confirm" button it says: `Please enter the street. Please enter the city.` etc.